# gitlab Can't save project. Please try again later

Tags: redis, gitlab

I just tried to create a new repository on my gitlab instance.
I get this error message:

Can't save project. Please try again later

I checked the logs which contained this:

```
Completed 200 OK in 599.9ms (Views: 571.8ms | ActiveRecord: 6.2ms)
Started GET "/projects/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-07 01:59:43 +0100
Processing by ProjectsController#new as HTML
  Rendered projects/_errors.html.haml (2.2ms)
  Rendered projects/new.html.haml within layouts/navless (154.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.haml (2.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_search.html.haml (40.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head_panel.html.haml (50.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.haml (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 223.1ms (Views: 214.9ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
Started POST "/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-07 01:59:56 +0100
Processing by ProjectsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=", "project"=>{"name"=>"repository", "path"=>"", "namespace_id"=>"6", "import_url"=>"", "description"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create project"}
  Rendered projects/_errors.html.haml (2.2ms)
  Rendered projects/create.js.haml (6.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 476.6ms (Views: 226.9ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
```

can't really see an issue any where in the logs.
I also checked the Enviroment:
bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production
    (in /home/git/gitlab)

```
System information
System:         Debian 7.2
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   1.9.3p194
Gem Version:    1.8.23
Bundler Version:1.3.5
Rake Version:   10.1.0

GitLab information
Version:        6.3.1
Revision:       09c6f66
Directory:      /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter:     mysql2
URL:            https://scm.domain.tld
HTTP Clone URL: https://scm.domain.tld/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@scm.domain.tld:some-project.git
Using LDAP:     no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:        1.7.9
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:          /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:            /usr/bin/git
```

I also ran this command:
bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production

```
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.9 ? ... OK (1.7.9)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
update hook up-to-date? ... yes
update hooks in repos are links: ...
group1 / repro1 ... ok
group1 / repro2 ... ok
group2 / repro3 ... ok
group1 / repro4... ok
group2 / repro5 ... ok
group5 / repro6 ... ok
group5 / repro7 ... ok
group3 / repro8 ... ok
group4 / repro9 ... ok
group1 / repro11 ... ok
group1 / repro12 ... ok
Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files:
        /home/git/repositories: OK
        /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
        /usr/bin/redis-cli: OK
gitlab-shell self-check successful

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
projects have namespace: ...
group1 / repro1 ... yes
group1 / repro2 ... yes
group2 / repro3 ... yes
group1 / repro4... yes
group2 / repro5 ... yes
group5 / repro6 ... yes
group5 / repro7 ... yes
group3 / repro8 ... yes
group4 / repro9 ... yes
group1 / repro11 ... yes
group1 / repro12 ... yes
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.7.10)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

My Redis Installation:

```
Package: redis-server
Source: redis
Version: 2:2.4.14-1
Installed-Size: 568
Maintainer: Chris Lamb <lamby@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7), libjemalloc1 (>= 2.1.1), adduser
Description-de: Persistente Schlüssel-Wert-Datenbank mit Netzwerkschnittstelle
 Redis ist eine Datenbank für Schlüssel-Wert-Paare. Sie ähnelt memcache,
 wobei die Datenmenge jedoch nicht flüchtig ist. Redis bietet zusätzlich
 native Unterstützung für die atomare Manipulation und Abfrage von
 Datenstrukturen wie Listen und Sets.
 .
 Der Datensatz wird vollständig im Speicher abgelegt und periodisch auf die
 Festplatte geschrieben.
Homepage: http://redis.io/
Description-md5: 9160ed1405585ab844f8750a9305d33f
Tag: implemented-in::c, role::program
Section: database
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/r/redis/redis-server_2.4.14-1_amd64.deb
Size: 234586
MD5sum: df2658e5243f8a99bc2205c16a154d0d
SHA1: 727b82f94497a578d35cc26a9bc29d141ff7131a
SHA256: 79e461471d7fa8ee046c441a184d1541ad343e9edf172a4d61659212eb4f4609
```

I don't get anything useful in the logs and don't know where to start.
Please help

Here are my config files:

```
production: &base
  gitlab:
    host: scm.domain.tld
    port: 443
    https: true
    email_from: build@domain.tld
    support_email: support@localhost
    default_projects_limit: 10
    signup_enabled: false
    default_projects_features:
      issues: false
      merge_requests: true
      wiki: false
      wall: false
      snippets: false
      public: false
  issues_tracker:
  gravatar:
    enabled: true
  omniauth:
    allow_single_sign_on: false
    block_auto_created_users: true
    providers:
  satellites:
    path: /home/git/gitlab-satellites/
  backup:
    path: "tmp/backups"
  gitlab_shell:
    repos_path: /home/git/repositories/
    hooks_path: /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
    upload_pack: true
    receive_pack: true
  git:
    bin_path: /usr/bin/git
    max_size: 5242880 # 5.megabytes
    timeout: 10
  extra:
```

my unicorn.rb

```
worker_processes 3
working_directory "/home/git/gitlab" 
listen "/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket", :backlog => 64
listen "127.0.0.1:8088", :tcp_nopush => true
timeout 30
pid "/home/git/gitlab/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/home/git/gitlab/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "/home/git/gitlab/log/unicorn.stdout.log"
preload_app true
GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true
check_client_connection false

before_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if old_pid != server.pid
    begin
      sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU
      Process.kill(sig, File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

gitlab-shell config

```
user: git
gitlab_url: "https://scm.domain.tld/"
http_settings:
  self_signed_cert: false
repos_path: "/home/git/repositories"
auth_file: "/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys"
redis:
  bin: /usr/bin/redis-cli
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 6379
  namespace: resque:gitlab
log_level: INFO
audit_usernames: false
```

Comment: I just checked on creating the repositories by hand, that works like I would have created them through the web frontend. But it doesn't make sense to always do that the complicated way. Also the other Admins and Developer will not like it.
I don't rellay know what goes wrong, nor do I find any debug option that helps me find the bug.

Comment: thx that made it better readable ^^ (the post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching and enabling the sql logs I found the Core Problem.
It was not the settings in the gitlab.yml.

They only tell the frontend where the web site is available or if it uses https or what port.

I updated from 6.2 to 6.3 and yesterday to 6.3.1

I thought that the update scripts would work well.
But they didn't

gitlab removed one of the project table columns.
They removed the column default_branch.
I set the column to default_branch can be null and it started to work again.

Thanks for the help.

Chris

Comment: Grreat feedback, in addition to my answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

You have a few similar issues:

- [issue 5023](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5023): Solved, i made two changes in `gitlab.yml`, `"host: localhost"` to `"host: 127.0.0.1"` and changed `"repos_path"` to the correct path.
- [issue 3328](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3328): I used the [Ubuntu method under Sidekiq](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide#sidekiq) and it worked for me.
  You need a different version of redis-server I'm guessing.
- [issue 3743](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/): MacOSx had some problem. so i changed mac to Ubuntu. I had success install it.

Comment: I tried the first issue suggestion.
Didn't change antything in the behaviour.
Checked my Redis-Server Version.
It's 2.4.14
So it should be high enough in the version count.

Comment: I'm using Debian Wheezy

Comment: I also tried to simply reinstall redit with apt-get purge redis-server and install redis-server. But that also didn't help??????
I didn't change any thing on the way it is setup.
I only moved the gitlab directory to home/git

Comment: Just to make shure:
I reinstalled it  according to the directions on the gitlab site.
I just reused the database, as there are no backlinks to any paths in there.